# Using yslow with Jenkins and phantomjs

Tags: jenkins, phantomjs, yslow

i am trying to access the yslow with phantomjs and jenkins.
https://github.com/marcelduran/yslow/wiki/PhantomJS

i referred to this url in doing that.

In that i can see some screenshots of the jenkins with TAP plugin,but i am not getting how to get the result in such UI .

when i executed the following command "phantomjs /tmp/yslow.js -i grade -threshold "B" -f junit http://in.news.yahoo.com > yslow.xml" from the command prompt ,its displaying the format of text in the console and i am getting yslow.xml file generated.

when i excute this command "phantomjs /tmp/yslow.js -i grade -threshold "B" -f tap "some url"> yslow.tap" ,in the command prompt, i am getting the yslow.tap  file generated.

can u please explain how to get such result from the jenkins in the front-end ...
This question might be stupid.but kindly answer this .n i am new to this enviromment.

Answer (score 1):

It's described in the Jenkins [TAP Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TAP+Plugin) wiki page:

1. Install the Jenkins TAP Plug-in from the Jenkins Plug-in Manager.
2. Check the option to publish TAP and configure a pattern for your test results.
3. Execute your build and analyze the results.